# My USB Headphones show up as USB Flash Drive

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, audio, usb-flash-drive

So, here's it. [It shows mine USB headset as non-functional USB Drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5WCc.png) for some reason. And it did not do that previously. It works perfectly as it was before, but still pops up as USB Drive. [And in Device Manager too.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkOhA.png) What can I do, so it wont show up? And solutions like disable it or hide it are not accepted, because I want it to run properly how it was before.

Comment: Perhaps the firmware allows for a driver install that never triggered before it "broke"?  Perhaps for debugging?   I myself am guessing that it is simply broken.  Your USB device is reporting itself as class 08h (mass storage) or 0Bh (smart card).  It is that simple.  I have written both USB drivers and firmware.  Good luck finding an "acceptable" solution.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas It fixed itself after reboot, so I found the "acceptable" solution, as you wished my luck with it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reboot it disappeared itself!